# Chrome/Firefox extension write on internal extension filesystem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

So i'm implementing a dark mode for my extension, and one of the thing i want to change is the default extension icon. Now i'm using the page_action in the manifest, then i can't use the `browserAction.setIcon`.

So one of the possible solutions to this problem is to use the `pageAction.setIcon`, but in order to do that i should make on every-tab an async request to get the tabId, because one of the required parameters is the tabId.

And i want to avoid to make too many calls, on something that is not going to change very often.
I want to change the extension icon only once every time the theme is changed by the user.

So i had that idea of provide the extension with both icons, and depending on the user selected theme going to overwrite the icon file with the dark or light version of the icon.

I searched everywhere, and stumbled on the FileSystem API, and drafted something like that:

```
chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(root) {
  root.getFile("images/icon.png",{}, 
    function(fileEntry){ 
       debugger; 
       console.log(fileEntry)
       fileEntry.moveTo(/*.....here going to do the file change....*/)
    }, 
    function(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  );
});
```

Now even if this solution looks like promising (haven't fully tested yet),i found that all the FileSystem Api are marked as Experimental (that could be fine) and Deprecated (copyto, moveto functions), so i don't think that it is a good idea to go for this solution (correct me if i'm wrong).

Here the link to the deprecated function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemEntry/copyTo

Now i can even store the icon to the local storage somehow, but the problem will still be how then i can write them to the images/icon.png file.

Is that possible? Or is there a better way?

Again i already searched the other SO questions using pageAction.setIcon and browserAction.setIcon, but i don't think they apply to my case.

Comment: getPackageDirectoryEntry won't help here as it's a virtual file system and it doesn't exist in Firefox. Modifying extension files will be detected by the browser and the extension will be disabled. Also, in Firefox extensions aren't unpacked internally so you would have to modify the entire xpi but they're signed. So, this idea won't work. You can probably just use an SVG icon that changes automatically based on prefers-color-scheme, I've seen an example like that.

Comment: ok that make sense. If u want to post it as an answer (because this comment is an answer for me) i'll accept it!